# Maximum items with given k tokens

Tags: python, algorithm

I have N elements in array. I can select the first item max of N times, the second item max of N-1 times and so on.

I have K tokens to use and need to use them so I can have the maximum number of items.

arr = [3, 4, 8] where array elements indicates tokens required for i'th item

```
    n = 10 , represents number of tokens I have

Output:

    3
```

**Explanation:**

```
We have 2 options here:

1. option 1: 1st item 2 times for 6 tokens (3*2) and second item once for 4 tokens (4*1)

2. option 2: 1st item 3 times for 9 tokens (3*3)

so maximum we can have 3 items
```

**Code:**

```
def process(arr,n):
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    
    size = len(arr)+1
    for i in range(0, len(arr), 1):
        size1 = size-1
        size -= 1
        while((sum+arr[i] <= n) and (size1 > 0)):
            size1 = size1 -1
            sum = sum + arr[i]
            count += 1

    return count;
```

But it worked for only few test cases, it failed for some hidden test cases.  I am not sure where I made a mistake.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: If this is from HackerRank, then the test cases which are failing will have large input values. For example, `arr` will have many values and `n` will be a large number. So, on large inputs, when your code takes a lot of time, test cases just fail because of timeout. Therefore, you need to optimize it.

Comment: Please share the link to the problem.

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh, I did this last week, do not have any link now

Comment: @MoosaSaadat, it is not hackerrank, some different app, don't remember

Comment: @learner checkout my solution below for the solution and the mistakes in your code...

Comment: @learner If my solution has solved your issues, Could you Accept/Upvote my answer, Please?

Comment: The greedy approach (ride the cheapest ride as many times as possible) should work. To speed things up, divide the remaining tokens by the cost of the cheapest ride: `rides = tokens_left / lowest_price`. If `rides` is greater than the number allowed, then set it equal to the number allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your greedy approach will fail for the test cases like this:

[8,2,1,1] 10

Your code will return 2 but the maximum will be 6.

I will use a **heap of a tuple** i.e. heap[(cost_of_ride,max_no_rides)] .

See the code below:

```
from heapq import *

def process(arr,n):
    count = 0
    
    heap = []
    
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        heappush(heap,(arr[i],-(len(arr)-i))) # Constructing min-heap with second index as negative of maximum number of rides 
    
    while(n>0 and heap):
        cost,no_of_rides = heappop(heap)
        no_of_rides = -1 * no_of_rides # Changing maximum no_of_rides from negative to positive
        
        div = n//cost

        # If the amount of money is not sufficient to calculate the last number of rides user could take
        if(div<no_of_rides):
            count += div
            break

        # Else decrement the number of tokens by minimum cost * maximum no_of_rides
        else:
            count += no_of_rides
            n -= no_of_rides*cost
    

    return count;
```

**Time Complexity** for the solution is: O(len(arr)*lg(len(arr))) or O(N*lg(N)).

Comment: I am trying to understand this, why we need to add negatives to heap liks `-(len(arr)-i))`?

Comment: @learner To have the maximum number of rides at the minimum cost... Although if you don't add a negative sign code will work in a similar manner...So if you want to edit the code...you are free to do that.

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me when we need to use negatives then? what will be the scenario. Also curious to know the explanation for N(Lg(N), how the Lg(N) when we have while loop that runs until we have elements in heap which holds the array elements.

Comment: @learner As we are using min-heap(inbuilt in python), So if you want elements to be in the max-heap format, Then you should add negative of that element.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def process(arr, n, res=[]):
    l=len(arr)
    for j in range(len(arr)+1):
        r=[arr[0]]*j
        if(sum(r)==n) or (sum(r)<n) and (l==1):
            yield len(res+r)
        elif(sum(r)<n):
            yield from process(arr[1:], n-sum(r), res+r)
        else:
            break
```

The idea is to iterate over all possible combinations of resulting tokens, more precisely - all options for individual token are just this token taken between `0` and `N` times, where `N` refers to tokens position, per your logic.
Discarding on the way combinations, which exceed `n`, ultimately returning generator, which produces lengths of produced vector of all tokens taken in all possible quantities (so in order to address your question - you need to take `max(...)` from it).

Outputs:

```py
>>> print(max(process([3,4,8],10)))

3

>>> print(max(process([8,2,1,1],10)))       

6

>>> print(max(process([10, 8, 6, 4, 2], 30)))

6
```

Comment: I added explanation - let me know if something needs to be more elaborated

Answer (score 0):

@learner your logic doesn't seem to be working properly.
Please try these inputs: arr = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2], n = 30.
As per your description answer should be **6** rides but your code would produce **3**

Answer (score 0):

Use a modified form a quickselect, where you select the next pivot based on the sum of the products of cost * max_times, but still sort based on just cost. This is worst-case O(n^2), but expected O(n).